# Package name changing

Tags: android-studio, package-name

I was created new android project in android studio, with name "maptest", after some changes I was changed the package name to another "name" ...
Now when I am running the app, on logcat window is showing old package name like this..

```
09-12 01:33:07.641  20740-20740/am.update.maptest I/Tag﹕ SlidingTabsBasicFragment onStop
09-12 01:33:07.641  20740-20740/am.update.maptest I/Tag﹕ HashvichFragment onStop
09-12 01:33:07.641  20740-20740/am.update.maptest I/Tag﹕ MainActivity onStop
```

and this code also returns old package name `/context.getPackageName()="am.update.maptest"/`

How can I fix it?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you update the package in both the manifest and app/build.gradle?

Comment: Yes I did. And the all imports in java files are new package name.

Comment: try running 'gradlew clean' and then 'gradlew assembleDebug' in your project folder